# Dealing with Non-standard HTTP Response Codes Exceptions in Java

Tags: java, http, exception, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I'm trying to write a HTTP client using the Java HTTP API. The problem I'm having is that when it encounters strange HTTP response codes (i.e. ones in the range 7XX) it throws and exception.

What's the best way of preventing the exception generated by non-standard response codes from causing my code to terminate?

Comment: I dont understand the Question. One good way of ignoring is to close eyes.

Comment: Catch the exception and then continue as usual?

Comment: What about using try and catch in Java?